# How to scale a big graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling, tikzscale

```
\begin{figure}[H]

\begin{tikzpicture}[->, node distance = 2cm]
\node[initial,state](A) {enter};
\node[state] (B) [below of=A]{1};
\node[state] (C) [below of=B]{2};
\node[state] (D) [right of=C] {i};
\node[state] (E) [right of=D] {4};
\node[state] (F) [above of=E] {5};
\node[state] (G) [right of=F] {6 };
\node[state] (H) [below of=G] {7};
\node[state] (I) [below of=H] {8};
\node[state, label=below:$s a w$] (J) [right of=I] { };
```

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that for more details what it means.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. What is `state`? What is `initial`? Do these come from some package or are they defined by you with `tikzset`? A ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) should start with `\documentclass`, include all relevant `\usepackage` commands, end with `\end{document}` and compile without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: You can reduce node distance, size of node shapes and used font size, It may help to increase text area size or rotate image to landscape orientation. For more, we need to se complete document with your image.

Comment: Please write a minimal working example because It's not easy to be Sherlock Holmes.

Answer (score 1):

When using `node distance` and `right of` it's difficult to scale the picture. There are for me two bad solutions like `resizebox` which scale everything and `transform shape` which gives the same result.
One possibility is to modify   `node distance = 2cm` .